# can't run Xamarin Mac samples

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio, monomac, xamarin.mac

I downloaded xamarin studio 5.7 starter edition and downloaded some demos from here:

https://github.com/xamarin/mac-samples

Everytime I try to compile i get this error:

"Error: The Unknown Edition of Xamarin.Mac does not support building outside of Xamarin Studio. Please go to https://store.xamarin.com to upgrade to the Business Edition. (ProgramName)"

If i create a new solution from scratch and choose "Unsupported/Monomac/C#" things compile without a problem and I get a Mac Osx Window.

How can i get these demos to compile? I am just trying to get started with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Mac license is needed to build or run applications. Go to Xamarin Studio > Account menu. It should look like this, before you can even open a Xamarin.Mac application in Xamarin Studio.[image]

Comment: there is no starter version?